# Python Selenium pop-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, I've decided to make TikTok massfollower, but can't go further than login.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from time import sleep

browser = Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.tiktok.com/foryou?lang=ru')
login = browser.find_element_by_class_name('jsx-3665539393')
login.click()

sleep(10)

login2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('channel-name-2Dwny')
login2.click()
```

It goes to TikTok website, then it presses the log-in button, and then there is pop-up window(I hope that's the right way to call it). But program can't find elements on this pop-up window, I thought that I should wait for pop-up to load, but there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are after is inside an `iframe` you need to switch to iframe first in order to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following css selector.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
browser.get('https://www.tiktok.com/foryou?lang=ru')
#Click on Login
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.jsx-3665539393"))).click()
#Click cookeis button
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.button-wrapper>button"))).click()

WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='tiktok']")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.close-modal-8dfIo"))))
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```